# Jest often crashes with a segmentation error in --watch mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

Without the viewing mode, just just stopped at the title RUNS SomeTest.tsx. When I added the `--watch` parameter, it started showing an error

```
A jest worker process (pid=9530) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGSEGV, exitCode=null. 
Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred. at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (node_modules/jest-runner/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:370:23).
```

I'm using `--experimental-vm-modules`. Node 18.12.1, Jest 29.6.2. OS: Linux, ElementaryOS

I tried to use parameters: `--maxWorkers=50%`, `--ranInBand`. Nothing worked